# How to do the equivalent of 'git rm' with libgit2?

Tags: git, libgit2

Using libgit2, I am able to do the equivalent of `git add` with `git_index_add`, but I am struggling to figure out how to achieve the equivalent of `git rm` on a file that has been deleted.

Comment: what is your platform? Perhaps want to link to the libgit2 version you are using?

Comment: Using C source from git://github.com/libgit2/libgit2.git, commit a0ce87c5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do that with the [`git_index_remove`](http://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/index/git_index_remove) function. As stage you'll probably want 0 (assuming you're not dealing with conflicts). It doesn't matter whether the file exists on the filesystem or not.

Comment: Ah, okay. I had seen that function, but had misunderstood the documentation. I assumed that _Remove an entry from the index_ meant that it would remove an entry that had been previously added with git_index_add - rather than marking a path for removal on commit. I'll give it a go, thanks.